# Finding a string in multiple workbooks, create a list, and then creating a hyperlink to it

Tags: excel, vba

This code was found online and works for me...

What I would like to do now is to make the search results an active hyperlink so that once you get the search results (columns A through d) Column C would be a hyperlink to the actual document/worksheet/cell.

not sure how to write it... .Cells(lRow, 5) = "=Hyperlink" & ((wbk.Name) & (wks.Name))
I noted the spot where I believe the appropriate code should be inserted

Thanks

Dave

```
Sub SearchFolders()


Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change as desired
strPath = "c:\MyFolder"
strSearch = Range("H2")

'H2 is where you type your search string

Set wOut = Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
lRow = 1
With wOut
    .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)

        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
            Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                    .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value

' Hyperlink code goes here?

                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(after:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next

        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: try `hyperlinkAddress = "'" & wbk.Name & "'!" & rFound.Address`     then  
        
        
        `.Range("C" & lRow).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("C" & lRow), Address:="", SubAddress:=hyperlinkAddress, TextToDisplay:=rFound.Value`

Comment: So I put this code in
....

And I get an error - Reference isn;t valid when i click on it.

Comment: Have you try recording the macro while you add the hyperlink manually? Similar answer with @k1dr0ck, below after record the macro and modify a bit. Example : `strPath = "c:\MyFolder": wbkName = "blablabla.xlsm" '(the wbk.name): wksName = "DATA" '(the wks.name): addr = "A10" '(the rFound.address)`. Add the hyperlink : `activesheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(lRow, 5), Address:=strPath & "\" & wbkName, SubAddress:=wksName & "!" & addr, TextToDisplay:="test"`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
.Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
.Cells(lRow, 3) = "=HYPERLINK(" & Chr(34) & "[" & strPath & "\" & strFile & "]'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rFound.Address & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "Click Here" & Chr(34) & ")"
.Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
```

Comment: It almost works.  It opens the correct sheet but then I get a Reference is not Valid error.  that said, the link does show the correct syntax... HYPERLINK("[c:\MyFolder\xxx.xlsm]Summary Sheet!$E$433","Click Here")

Comment: @DavidKurzman tested it on my side with my own values of the path, file name, sheet name and cell address and it works, try using `rFound.Address(False, False)`

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am getting the same error.  I assume that .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value  should be switched to     .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Address(False, False) ?  The syntax looks correct 
but it does not go to the correct cell.  FYI.  The file being opend has macros and when I open the document I enable them but I don't think that should cause a prob...

Comment: I found the error!  the worksheet has a space in It "Summary Sheet".  If I change the name to "Summary" It works.  any way I can keep it as "Summary Sheet" as i have other macros that would need to be modified for me to make that change?

Comment: @DavidKurzman try using the updated hyperlink formula above added single quotes before and after the sheet name, you can also read here https://superuser.com/questions/1658283/excel-internal-hyperlinks-to-worksheets-with-space-in-their-names

Comment: Thanks for your reply but because the worksheet is a variable wks.name I am not certain how to code it.

Comment: @DavidKurzman as i said in my previous reply i updated the code above

Comment: Hi there,  I would like to make 1 more addition,  I would like to have an additional column that shows the actual text in the found cell. 
.Cells(lRow, 5) = ???
For example if I search "Big"  I want to see the results which could include "Big" "Bigger" or "Biggest".  Hope this makes sense

Comment: @DavidKurzman the actual text found value is already in `.Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value`, i dont get the what you mean, find other values which contains partially the search value?